# Combining 4 elements (nested loops)

Tags: php, mysql, loops, nested

In the database I have a list of meals. In any given type of food I a meal (1 - breakfast, 2 - II breakfast, 3 - lunch, 4 - dinner), and protein, carbohydrates and fat (all in grams) that are present in the meal. I have to match every meal with every meal to get a full diet for the day. One meal is stored in the database as a type of meal, for example, "1,2,4" - that can be used for all meals except dinner. I did something like:

```
foreach ($meal1 as $row1)
{
    foreach ($meal2 as $row2)
    {
        foreach ($meal3 as $row3)
        {
            foreach ($meal4 as $row4)
            {
                // Here merge operations meals and entry to the array
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The database contains only 100 meals, and the script performs more than 10 seconds (no wonder). What will happen when it is 10,000 meals? Do you have any ideas to do it well and optimally? $ meal1, $ meal2, $ meal3, $ meal4 include meals query to filter the type of meal (breakfast, second breakfast, lunch, dinner). I need this such a form when I connect every meal with every meal, I counted how many meal has protein, carbohydrates and fats and how it will be missing, for example, 20 grams of protein in a meal to the daily requirements, to dinner, I will give snacks (eg. Yogurt, banana, etc.).

Well, someone has an idea for an optimal play with basis weights meals that do not have to add snacks? In the database, the meal has a weight (grams), calorific value (kcal) and protein (in grams), carbohydrates (in grams), and fat (grams). But this option I know that probably the hardest, so please help in this option (with snacks), unless someone has an idea for the second option, it will be great.

Thank you in advance for your help.

@edit:

Database scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recipes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `weight` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kcal` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `protein` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `carbohydrates` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fats` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Code:

```
$proteinPerDay = 229;
$carbohydratesPerDay = 229;
$fatsPerDay = 51;

$result_1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE type LIKE '%1%'");
while ($data_1 = $result_1->fetch_assoc())
{
    $meal_1[] = $data_1;
}

$result_2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE type LIKE '%2%'");
while ($data_2 = $result_2->fetch_assoc())
{
    $meal_2[] = $data_2;
}

$result_3 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE type LIKE '%3%'");
while ($data_3 = $result_3->fetch_assoc())
{
    $meal_3[] = $data_3;
}

$result_4 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE type LIKE '%4%'");
while ($data_4 = $result_4->fetch_assoc())
{
    $meal_4[] = $data_4;
}

$diet = array();
foreach ($meal_1 as $row1)
{
    foreach ($meal_2 as $row2)
    {
        if ($row1 == $row2)
        {
            continue;
        }

        foreach ($meal_3 as $row3)
        {
            if ($row1 == $row3 || $row2 == $row3)
            {
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($meal_3 as $row4)
            {
                if ($row1 == $row4 || $row2 == $row4 || $row3 == $row4)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                $proteinPerDayFind = $row1['protein'] + $row2['protein'] + $row3['protein'] + $row4['protein'];
                $carbohydratesPerDayFind = $row1['carbohydrates'] + $row2['carbohydrates'] + $row3['carbohydrates'] + $row4['carbohydrates'];
                $fatsPerDayFind = $row1['fats'] + $row2['fats'] + $row3['fats'] + $row4['fats'];

                // I check to see whether the protein, fats and carbohydrates are sufficient. If something is not enough for the daily demand, it will add snacks.

                $diet[$row1['id'] . $row2['id'] . $row3['id'] . $row4['id']][0] = $row1;
                $diet[$row1['id'] . $row2['id'] . $row3['id'] . $row4['id']][1] = $row2;
                $diet[$row1['id'] . $row2['id'] . $row3['id'] . $row4['id']][2] = $row3;
                $diet[$row1['id'] . $row2['id'] . $row3['id'] . $row4['id']][3] = $row4;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your full fragment of code, database schema, and sample of raw data

Comment: If "$meal1, $meal2, $meal3, $meal4 include meals query to filter the type of meal", but are not necessarily connected (for example $meal2 does not depend on $meal1, you can just get them sequentially, instead of getting them in a loop. Avoid looped queries as much as possible. Performance-wise, it's better to get a bigger (unfiltered) result from the database (and filter it in php) than to get them from a looped query

Comment: I added the database schema and code.

Comment: Normalise your design